# why i am not able to access Gui panel at 2812 port 

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, monit

I followed this http://fosscasts.com/screencasts/6-System-Monitoring-With-Monit

```
set daemon 20
set logfile /var/log/monit.log

set mailserver smtp.gmail.com port 587
        username "myemail" password "mypswd"
        using tlsv1
        with timeout 30 seconds

set alert myemail

set httpd port 2812 and
        use address myurldns.net
        allow myurldns.net
        allow admin:monit


check system localhost
        if loadavg (1min) > 4 then alert
        if loadavg (5min) > 2 then alert
        if memory usage > 75% then alert
        if cpu usage (user) > 70% then alert
        if cpu usage (system) > 30% then alert
        if cpu usage (wait) > 20% then alert

check process apache2 with pidfile /var/run/apache2.pid
        group www
        start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"
        stop program  = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
        if children > 250 then restart
        if loadavg(5min) greater than 10 for 8 cycles then stop
        if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

when i run

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/monit start
```

start deamon comes but i am not able to acces gui panel on 2812 port

Answer (score 0):

The error log can display notifications as well. Does the intended task actually work as you want it to, even with this message? For example, Apache says stuff like "Apache started on port 80" and "starting child threads" and such. Not a big deal, since it's only notifying you.